# MPAndroidChart: constant position of Y-axis lines independent of data

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I'm using MPAndroid chart to display a line chart.

The chart is updated with different data and of course, when the data changes, the y-axis lines and the zoom level is changed because of the different sets of input data.

Is there any way to maintain the position of the y-axis lines and only change their labels according to the new data?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of tries and investigations, it seems that I found a solution just after posting the question.

Just in case someone else needs this, I used the `setLabelCount` function before but never the one with the `force` parameter.
The solution is:

```
mChart.getAxisLeft().setLabelCount(visibleYCount, true);
```

Forcing the label count will assure the number of y-axis lines and thus, their position is stable with different data sets.